Image of injective Lie group homomorphism is lie group
I am reading about Lie subgroups in J. Lee, "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds"". Here is the proposition and its proof that I can't quite understand

Proposition 7.17. If $F: G \rightarrow H$ is an injective Lie group homomorphism, the image of $F$ has a unique smooth manifold structure such that $F(G)$ is a Lie subgroup of $H$ and $F: G \rightarrow F(G)$ is a Lie group isomorphism.


Proof. Since a Lie group homomorphism has constant rank, it follows from the global rank theorem that $F$ is a smooth immersion. Proposition 5.18 shows that
$F(G)$ has a unique smooth manifold structure such that it is an immersed submanifold of $H$ and $F$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. It is a Lie group (because $G$ is), and it is a subgroup for algebraic reasons, so it is a Lie subgroup. Because $F: G \rightarrow F(G)$ is a group isomorphism and a diffeomorphism, it is a Lie group isomorphism.

My question is about the last part. I understood, that it is, indeed, immersed submanifold (so it has proper smooth structure) and for algebraic reasons $\text{Im}(F)$ is subgroup, but why multiplication and inverse map are smooth in induced smooth structure?

It is simply because the problem is local and, locally, you are just using the restrictions of group operations in $H$.
